# regex uppercase to lowercase

Tags: regex, apache-flex, replace, lowercase

Is it possible to transform regexp pattern match to lowercase?

```
var pattern:RegExp;
var str:String = "HI guys";
pattern = /([A-Z]+)/g;
str = str.replace(pattern, thisShouldBeLowerCase);
```

Output should look like this: "hi guys"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this, but replace the pattern with exactly what you need:

```
public static function lowerCase(string:String, pattern:RegExp = null):String
{
    pattern ||= /[A-Z]/g;
    return string.replace(pattern, function x():String
    {
        return (arguments[0] as String).toLowerCase();
    });
}

trace(lowerCase('HI GUYS', /[HI]/g)); // "hi GUYS";
```

That [`arguments`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/arguments.html) variable is an internal variable referencing the function parameters.  Hope that helps,

Lance

Comment: Thx, I'll give it a try, but it looks promising :)

Answer (score 7):

```
var html = '<HTML><HEAD><BODY>TEST</BODY></HEAD></HTML>';
var regex = /<([^>]*)>/g;
html = html.replace(regex, function(x) { return x.toLowerCase() });
alert(html);
```

Answer (score 4):

to lowercase

```
s/[A-Z]/\l&/g
```

and to uppercase

```
s/[a-z]/\u&/g
```

Answer (score 1):

Change all upper english letters to lower in ActionSctipn 3

```
var pattern:RegExp = /[A-Z]/g;
contentstr = contentstr.replace(pattern,function(a:String,b:int,c:String):String { return a.toLowerCase() } );
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible using regex. You can only replace `A` with `a`, `B` with `b`, etc. Not all at once.

Why not simply use [`toLowerCase()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=09_Working_with_Strings_10.html)?

Comment: I want to replace html tags, and those are in upper case, but XHTML allows only lowercase tags, therefore I need them in lowercase

Answer (score 0):

you can use a function as the second argument for string.replace

in your case you could use

```
var pattern:RegExp;
var str:String = "HI guys";
pattern = /([A-Z]+)/g;
str = str.replace(pattern, function(search, match1) { 
   return match1.toLowerCase() }
);
```

read more about it here
[Javascript: how to pass found string.replace value to function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712874/javascript-how-to-pass-found-string-replace-value-to-function/4712975#4712975)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert complete string to lowercase then  use `.toLowerCase()` or `.toUpperCase()` in javascript.

If you want to replace a particular  letter with lowercase in a String then `Regex` is better.