# Javascript: how to pass found string.replace value to function?

Tags: javascript, regex, function, replace

When I have something like this:

```
var str = "0123";
var i = 0;
str.replace(/(\d)/g,function(s){i++;return s;}('$1'));
alert(i);
```

Why does "i" equal 1 and not 4? 
Also, is it possible to pass the real value of $1 to a function (in this case 0,1,2,3) ?

Comment: D'oh, the answer to the first part is because the inside function gets executed before the replace function gets the value. But I still don't know the answer to the second question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you use `string.replace(rx,function)` then the function is called with the following arguments:

- The matched substring
- Match1,2,3,4 etc (parenthesized substring matches)
- The offset of the substring
- The full string

[You can read all about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

In your case $1 equals Match1, so you can rewrite your code to the following and it should work as you desire:

```
var str = "0123";
var i = 0;
str.replace(/(\d)/g,function(s,m1){i++;return m1;});
alert(i);
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware I could pass a function as the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
function(s){i++;return s;}('$1')
```

Creates the function and immediately evaluates it, passing `$1` as an argument. The `str.replace` method already receives a string as its second argument, not a function. I believe you want this:

```
str.replace(/(\d)/g,function(s){i++;return s;});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function, which increments `i` once, and then returns the string `'$1'`.

To pass the value to a function, you can do:

```
str.replace(/\d/g, function (s) { /* do something with s */ });
```

However, it looks like you don't actually want to replace anything... you just want a count of the number of digits. If so, then `replace` is the wrong tool. Try:

```
i = str.match(/\d/g).length;
```